# check one of RequiredField is not filled

Tags: asp.net, validation

i have register form in asp, it has 30 input box that all of them  have RequiredFieldValidator
. when user click on submit how can i found out that at least one of input is not filled and show error next to the submit button and input control?

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>title :</legend>
        <asp:Table ID="Table3" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server"> :</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMadrakTahsili" runat="server" CssClass="Width"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtMadrakTahsili"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">reshte :</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReshteTahsili" runat="server" CssClass="Width"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator25" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtReshteTahsili"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell7" runat="server">mahale akhz :</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell8" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMahalAkhzMadrak" runat="server" CssClass="Width"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtMahalAkhzMadrak"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">avg</asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMoadel" runat="server" CssClass="Width"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtMoadel"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </fieldset>
```

if one og inpuut is not filled , show error next to this button to !

```
<p style="float:left; clear:both;">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ثبت اطلاعات" Height="54px" 
            style="margin-right: 0" Width="119px" onclick="Button1_Click" /></p>
```

Comment: if i do not show error next to button , user may confused that why form will not submitted . i want to show a general message(next to submit button ) and special error(next to input control ) to tell the user

Comment: Did you try what I suggested you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="The textbox is empty" Text="*" 
Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtMadrakTahsili">
```

When you use `Text="*"` it will be shown next to `Textbox` if you placed it near the `Textbox`.

The `ErrorMessage` property is useful when you want to show all validation errors together.

So if you want to show `Error Messages` associated with the `Textboxes` then I suggest you use `ASP.NET` `ValidationSummary` control

**[Validation Summary Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd5c6s6h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

**EXAMPLE:**

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationErrors" runat="server"
DisplayMode="BulletList" HeaderText="There are some errors on the page./>
```

Comment: `ErrorMessage="Input Plz" Text="*"` show error dicription in summary and * next to input control

Comment: it works good , how can i show only on error in Valaidation summary ?

Comment: @Moslem7026 Sorry but I didnt understand you properly.

Comment: `<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="Fill All Inputs">
</asp:ValidationSummary>` and set `ErrorMessage=""` for all input solved my problem